# as you know which is the last page of a jasper report?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a document that can generate multiple pages, but only in the last need to print a value, how can I identify within the structure of the jasper report which is the last page to display the desired value?

Answer (score 1):

You could use following Expression:

```
$V{PAGE_NUMBER}==$V{PAGE_COUNT}
```

Both are Defined Variables in jasper-reports.

Comment: This expression is not correct, we are comparing the current page with the register number in jasper report detail band. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @jamlhet Where should your value be put? Behind the Detail Band? Or at the end of the last page? Just to clarify.

Comment: End of the last page.

Comment: Why not just put it into the band "Last Page Footer". That should suite your needs.